# how to update xml type with thai character or with UTF-8 characterSet

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8

i am trying to update xmtype column in oracle database.
i have some thai character in xml string,but when i update it it stores with garbage character.
here is what i have tried

```
update tbltdocumentxml 
set XMLCONTENT= (select  XMLType((select  convert('<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "AL32UTF8"?><custominfo> มาลี มงกุฏ มงกุฏ </custominfo>', 'UTF8') myValue from dual)) abc from dual)
where XMLDOCUMENTID= 'XML000000803';
commit;
```

But this result in garbage character where ever thai character are there in xml string.
looking for help

Comment: What program are you using to run the statement?  What is your database character set, `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`?

Comment: i am running it through SQL developer and its encoding  character set is AL32UTF8